# What is the cause and fix for this error msg: "Error while fetching object Could not resolve scope ORG.ENV"

Tags: apigee

I created a new environment (org = TST and environment = TST02)

When I go to almost all pages in the Mgmt UI, I get this error:

Error while fetching object
Could not resolve scope TST.TST02

Ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: My suggestion is to go with Apigee Support request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that Analytics is not enabled for the environment TST02 in the org TST.

Are you in a on-premises setup?

Comment: I'm on-prem.  gee, it would be nice if the error message said that...  Also, the OPDK Ops Guide has a very detailed section on creating a new environment and it doesn't say to make a service call to setup Analytics...You live; you learn!

Comment: Agreed.  We need to improve that error message.  Meanwhile, if you enable Analytics, that error should go away.

Comment: "enable analytics"?  I got this from a case and it worked: 

curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -u mgeiser@xxx.com:xxxxx -X POST "http://xxxxxmgr01.us.xxx.net:8080/v1/analytics/groups/ax/axgroup001/scopes?org=TST&env=TST03"

Comment: "enable analytics" can be as simple as running the "enable-ax.sh" script from the bin directory from the apigee installation. It will ask you the org and environment name.